# invertible matrix in real number

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A,B \in M_{n}( R )$. (They're both in real numbers.) There is an invertible matrix $P \in M_{n}(C)$ (P is in complex number), where $PAP^{-1} = B$. Show that there is  an invertible matrix $Q \in M_{n}(R)$ where $QAQ^{-1} = B$.

I've tried this way, but it doesn't work:
$$P = C + iD$$
$$P^{-1} = E + iF$$
where $C$ and $E$ are real parts and $iD$ and $iF$ are imaginary parts.
$$PAP^{-1} = (C+iD)A(E+iF) = B$$
$$\Rightarrow CAE - DAF + i(DAE + CAF) = B$$
B, A, C, F, E are real, so $DAE + CAF = 0$
$$\Rightarrow B = CAE - DAF$$

also $$PP^{-1} = I$$ 
$$\Rightarrow (C+iD)(E+iF) = I$$
$$\Rightarrow CE - DF + i(DE + CF) = I$$
again $DE+CF = 0$

I'm trying to change $CAE - DAF$ into $QAQ^{1}$, but I can't.

Comment: Do you know about the rational canonical form?

Comment: The answer is here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1129628/similarity-of-real-matrices-over-mathbbc. If you resort to a more advanced treatment of similarity, then it is easy. $A$ is similar to $B$ over some field if and only if they have the same elementary divisors. So if $A$ and $B$ are over the reals, their elementary divisors over $\mathbb{C}$ can just be multiplied to give elementary divisors over $\mathbb{R}$.