# What are some transformations that leave the eigenvalues of a matrix unchanged?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, transformation, invariance

I'm looking for transformations (isometries or not) that leave the spectrum of a matrix unchanged. I've only been able to come up with

- similarity transformations and
- transposition (is transposition in fact just a similarity transformation?).

**What are some others?** Thanks.

Comment: Transposition leaves not just the spectrum but the Jordan normal form unchanged, so it is in fact a similarity transform. (I suspect most things worthy of being called "transformations" would have the same property if they preserve the raw spectrum).

Comment: It is almost surely the only transformations that leave unchanged the spectrum.

Comment: @HenningMakholm So you're saying that we can write transposition of a matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ like $A^T=P^{-1}AP$ for some invertible $P$, or is it only if $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$?

Comment: @JeanMarie This is also my feeling, but can it be seen in a more rigorous way?

Comment: @Lovsovs: The Jordan-form argument gives you a $P\in \mathbb C^{n\times n}$ that does the trick. Now, real matrices that are similar over $\mathbb C$ [are also similar over $\mathbb R$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57242/similar-matrices-and-field-extensions).

Comment: Let $A$ and $B$ two square matrices with same eigenvalues. Then it can be shown that there is a nonsingular $P$ such that $$A=P^{-1}BP$$ the same way the svd theorem is proved

Comment: @polfosol Huh, I didn't know the implication went the other way as well. This answers my question. If you post this as an answer with either a heuristic argument for its truth or a reference containing the proof, I'll gladly accept.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Thank you! A last question: Is it correct that sim.transforms are, in general, not isometries, but can be?

Comment: @polfosol: How about $A=({}^1_0\;{}^1_1)$ and $B=({}^1_0\;{}^0_1)$?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Well, that was unexpected `:p`

Comment: Um, wait a moment -- I suppose a "similarity transformation" ought to mean $A\mapsto P^{-1}AP$ for some _fixed_ $P$. My argument doesn't show that transposition is of _that_ form, only that _for each $A$_ there is such a $P$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes, thank you, that was clear (in my head, not the way I wrote it).

Comment: Indeed there cannot be any $P$ such that $A^T=P^{-1}AP$ for all $A$. The only $P$s that work for $A=({}^1_0\;{}^0_2)$ will be diagonal matrices, but there is no diagonal $P$ that works for $A=({}^1_0\;{}^1_1)$ because we need to get $A^T=({}^1_1\;{}^0_1)$ but a product of upper triangular matrices is upper triangular.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Also $A\mapsto PAP^{-1}$ is an algebra homomorphism, $A\mapsto A^T$ is an "anti-homomorphism," because $(AB)^T=B^TA^T$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the transformation is linear and the underlying field is algebraically closed, it is known that all possible choices are in the form of $A\mapsto P^{-1}AP$ or $A\mapsto P^{-1}A^\top P$, where $P$ is any constant but invertible matrix.

For other fields, you should first define what does it mean by *"leaving the spectrum unchanged"*, since a matrix may not have a full spectrum over  the ground field. Anyway, you may search for any known results on the internet or on any journal database. Some relevant keywords are **"spectrum preserving linear map"** and **"linear preservers of spectrum/eigenvalues"**.