# If $A,B$ are matrices over $K\subset L$ that are similar over $L$, when are they similar over $K$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, field-theory

I know a proof of this for $\mathbb C/\mathbb R$, which I assume should hold for extensions of the form $L=K(\alpha)$, $\alpha$ algebraic, $K$ infinite. What is a minimal set of conditions on $L/K$ for this to hold?

Comment: It always holds (e.g. due to the uniqueness of rational canonical form); see [Similar matrices and field extensions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/57242/568204).

Comment: I think this holds for any field extension. By the Jordan normal form, (I think) $A$ is similar to $B$ over a field $K$ iff for any $P \in K[x]$, $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ have the same rank, which concludes.