# Question regarding similar matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory

Let $A,B \in GL(n,\mathbb{C})$ be similar, i.e. $\exists C \in GL(n,\mathbb{C}): A = C^{-1}BC.$ Then i have the following question:

*I know, that under certain circumstances a complex matrix can be (unitarily) similar to a real matrix. But if we assume that $A \in GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ is similar to $B$ inside $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$ in the above sense, then does this imply $B \in GL(n,\mathbb{R})$?*

In particular, if this were the case, then $A$ and $B$ would be similar inside $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ according to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57242/similar-matrices-and-field-extensions) considering the field extension $\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Do you know what « unitary similar » means?

Comment: Aren't the matrices $\begin{pmatrix}1&z\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ similar for all (real and) complex numbers $z$?

Comment: @Plop Two square matrices $A$ and $B$ are unitarily similar matrices if there exists a matrix $P$ s.th. $PA=BP$ and $P$ is a unitary matrix.

Comment: @GregMartin Sorry, but i still don´t quite get your example.

Comment: @Greg All *non-zero* numbers $z$

Comment: Diagonalize the matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{pmatrix}$ over $\mathbb C$ to get $B=\begin{pmatrix}i&0\\0&-i\end{pmatrix}$. The columns of $C$ will be (complex) eigenvectors of $A$, corresponding to complex eigenvalues $i, -i$, respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no. As a counterexample, consider
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&1\\0&2}, \quad B = \pmatrix{1 & i\\0 & 2}, \quad C = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&i}.
$$